# Is it possible to add custom annotation without pin in xcode?

Tags: annotations, android-mapview

I need the annotation in the center of map just show me the title and no pin.

Is it possible to do so in Xcode? if yes how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to create custom views instead of pins - see a great example MapCallouts from Apple, showing how to achieve this http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MapCallouts/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009746

in general, you need to implement a `- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation` method and return a custom view for you annotation (i believe the one with title and so on);

Comment: but I don't need any pin at all